# Can Chrome websockets be used by other applications?

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, websocket

I am trying to make myself familiar with websockets. It is possible to create tunnels with websockets

https://github.com/erebe/wstunnel

You can even tunnel VPN protocols like wireguard through it.

Would it be possible to use Chrome and Nginx in a similar way?
A websocket connection is established between both. A client uses the websocket of Chrome to funnel its traffic through the tunnel. On the nginx end data leaves the tunnel and gets forwarded to the internet.

Like: Client --> Chrome Websocket --> Websocket Tunnel --> Server --> Internet

Will this work in principle? Can clients (like other programs running on the machine or different devices on the network) use the websockets opened by Chrome? Is there a limitation on what the client can be? Are websockets standardized in a way that they are compatible (like a wstunnel client but nginx endpoint)?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you opened a WebSocket connection with application A - application B can't access it unless your applications can talk let's say via IPC. What exactly you mean by `use the websockets opened by Chrome` ?

Comment: Another application on the system should use the websocket to make outgoing connections.